Struggling to gauge progress first year PhD
I'm in my first year of my PhD (first 2 months) in the UK. I’m struggling a bit with knowing what’s expected of me and how much work I’m supposed to have got done by this point. I’m feeling kind of bad about it because I feel like I’ve been dumb and just repeated the same experiment multiple times to make starting material when I didn’t need to do that and I just wasted time when I could have been more efficient. I’m also worried my supervisor thinks I’m not independent enough because I keep asking them lots of questions and reviewing my plan for the week/day. I also feel like I barely know what’s going on half the time. Do you have any advice?

Talk to your advisor.

The first two months are hardly the first year, let alone a significant part of your PhD. Why do you already apply such high standards and pressure to yourself?

What sort of affirmation are you looking for? Start by jotting down a few questions, then discuss them with your advisor. And figure out whom, if anyone, you’re currently comparing yourself to.

State your field for better answers

Do not assume that your supervisor thinks those things. They KNOW those things. They know you are not fully independent. They know that you have no idea what's going on half the time. They know and expect that you will repeat things and make what can be construed as dumb mistakes.
This is part of your training. Keep reading the literature. Keep asking questions (but do start thinking about them more before asking) and keep building your independence. It takes time. Outside of my absolute best PhD students, nobody in my group has ever really been a net positive within the first 6 months (most take a year).

Your supervisor will thank you if you have at least read the wikipedia page before asking that question.

@DDuck "We've tried nothing and we're all out of ideas", yes a minimal gesture is appreciated. Among my current crop of 3 new PhDs... one feels the need to knock on my door and inform me of every single mundane activity, achievement, task they are doing, and also ask every question imaginable that could be answered by wikipedia, a colleague, a textbook etc.. Is it annoying? At times yes. On busy days, very much so.... but they are a first year student in their first semester, so I smile and nod, help them along, and try to get them to build some of that confidence and independence.

Also make sure to record answers from your advisor so that if you must ask a basic question, you will only need to do so once (for that question at least).

My experience is that asking a lot of questions is a good thing, not a bad one. But the best, perhaps the only, way to get a handle on your position and progress is to have a chat with your supervisor. Ask if they have any concerns. Ask what you might do better.
You don't go to grad school to prove to the world that you don't need to go to grad school.
Relax a bit and have a friendly chat. It is the best students that ask questions. Possibly because they don't occur to some others.

As others said, talk to your advisor. If this is not their first PhD they will have a canned answer along the lines of "you are fine, you are learning, come to me with questions, read this and that, ...". If this is their first PhD, well, you will both learn together :)
The fact that you started a PhD is not some miraculous event that changed you from a student that was more or less on autopilot to a senior researcher. Like everything, the transition takes time.
One of the things you must be aware of is that there will be a gray area in your time (a few months to a year or so) where you will learn what you need to know in order to discover new things. Sure, you can be the kind of student who jumps right away on a discovery and wraps up their PhD in 6 months. I certainly was not one of them (I switched my PhD topic after a year because I discovered something way more interesting).
The other thing is that you cannot gauge your progress yourself. What you think is slow can be OK or fast, and vice-versa. There are some general highlights (in Europe for instance you are usually expected to publish an article, and have another one on the way) but they are general.
Finally research is not manufacturing: you cannot plan to do 2 minor discoveries per week and 1 major every 3 months, preferably in September.
So do not worry, discuss with your advisor and possibly some older colleagues and enjoy the ride. This is a wild ride but, boy, it is great.
